# Create Drop Down using angularJs from json

Tags: java, json, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm having json as below

```
 var content = [{
  "DocList": [
    {
      "Events": [
        {
          "CategoryName": "PressStatements",
          "DisplayName": "Press Statements",
          "ID": 9
        },
        {
          "CategoryName": "Reports",
          "DisplayName": "Reports",
          "ID": 10
        }
      ],
      "Heading": "News 2",
      "PageID": 23,
       "Date": "\/Date(1454537792000)\/"

    },
    {
      "Events": [
        {
          "CategoryName": "Research",
          "DisplayName": "Research",
          "ID": 6
        }
      ],
      "Heading": "Heading",
      "PageID": 20,
      "Date": "\/Date(1437417792000)\/"
    }
]}
];


$scope.data=content;
  $scope.filterItems = function(g) {
    //console.log('filterItems is run');
    var ret = $filter('filter')(g.NewsList,"");
    //g.filteredItemCount = ret.length
    return ret
};
```

wanted to create a drop-down for Events which will show select option of a CategoryName. And also filter it out details depending on the selection of a CategoryName from Events. Below code just showing me first element from each object.Like i'm getting select option as PressStatements and Research but i also wants Reports in dropdown.

```
<select ><option ng-repeat="item1 in (filtered = filterItems(d))">   {{item1.Events[0].DisplayName}}</option></select>
```

Comment: so, what is the problem?

Comment: in dropdown im getting PressStatements and Research

Comment: so Reports is missing in dropdown

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i got all options in select tag

```
$scope.abms = [];
 console.log(news[0].NewsList);

angular.forEach(news[0].NewsList, function(newsItems, index) {
  angular.forEach(newsItems.CategoryList, function(category, index){
    $scope.abms.push(category.DisplayName);
  });
});
```

Comment: is there any way around to do this?